# Multiple comboboxes value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am creating a page where the user choose to upload some files,then choose the file type of each file from a combo box then submit. 'reports' are the files the user chosed to upload, i mapped over them to show them in rows then the user can choose for each file the crossponding file type. How to get the value in the combo box for each file the user uploaded? My code runs for only one file but how can be edited to be for multiple comboboxes?

[image]

```
const [fileType, setFileType] = useState('');

    const fileChangeHandler = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        
        setFileType(event.target.value);
   
    }
return (
<div>
        {reports.map((report, i) => (
            <div className="file-row" key={i}>
                <div>{report.name}</div>
                <div>
                    <select className='frm-select' value={fileType} onChange={fileChangeHandler}>
                        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select File Type</option>
                        {fileTypeOptions.map((option) => (
                            <option key={option.id}>{option.FileName}</option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                </div>
                {renderFileRow(report, i,fileType)}
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: The problem is there is only logic for one fileType for all the files.  You could put the report.name and select and fileType useState into a separate component that handles a single row.

Comment: A combobox is a UI control that is a combination (hence the name) of a drop down menu (which is what you get with a select in HTML) and a text input (an input of type text). HTML doesn't have any native controls that are represented as comboboxes. You have a select element, which is *just* a drop down menu without the text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use a map (like an object but more dynamic) instead of a plain string. I'm not sure you have `report.id` or not, so I'm using `report.name` for this example

```
//create an empty map for all file types
const [fileTypes, setFileTypes] = useState<{ [key: string]: string }>({});

    const fileChangeHandler = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>, reportName: string) => {
        //it will return an object for all file types
        setFileTypes({
           ...fileTypes,
           [reportName]: event.target.value
        });
   
    }
return (
<div>
        {reports.map((report, i) => (
            <div className="file-row" key={i}>
                <div>{report.name}</div>
                <div>
                    <select className='frm-select' value={fileTypes[report.name]} onChange={(e) => fileChangeHandler(e, report.name)}>
                        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select File Type</option>
                        {fileTypeOptions.map((option) => (
                            <option key={option.id}>{option.FileName}</option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                </div>
                {renderFileRow(report, i,fileType)}
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

The final results of `fileTypes` will be like this

```
{
   "report name 1": "pdf",
   "report name 2": "image"
}
```

Here is how we access file type for each report

```
fileTypes[report.name]
```

Comment: I got this error 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.' at the value in the select statment

Comment: I updated the code for you. We need to set specific type for `useState`. In this case, it should be `useState<{ [key: string]: string; }>({});`

Comment: please let me know if you're still facing that problem, @ReactDeveloper

Comment: One more question,i have the submit button (disabled by default).Can you tell me how to check if all the combo boxes have values to enable the submit button?

Comment: If all reports have file types, you can check array length, if `reports.length === Object.keys(fileTypes).length`, and then you can activate your button. @ReactDeveloper